# Decode multiple layers of a nested JSON with Swift

Tags: json, swift

I have trouble decoding json data using SwiftUI, I have the following json.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "project:xxxxxx",
            "project_manager": {
                "employee_id": "employee:xxxxxx",
                "id": "employee:xxxxxx",
                "person_id": "person: xxxxxx",
                "name": "Peter Post"
            },
            "project_status": {
                "id": "projectstatus:xxxxxx",
                "label": "active"
            },
            "created": "2019-01-08 15:39:59",
            "modified": "2019-01-24 14:39:13",
            "created_at": "2019-01-08 15:39:59",
            "updated_at": "2019-01-24 14:39:13",
            "url": "https://url.com/projects/project/view?id=000",
...
```

I'm decoding the json with the following code

```
import Foundation

struct Projects: Decodable {
    let data: [Data]
}

struct Data : Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let url: String
    let organization: Organization?
    let project_status: ProjectStatus?
}

struct Organization : Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String?
}

struct ProjectStatus: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let id: String?
    let label: String?
}
```

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class NetworkingManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var projectList = Projects(data: [])


    init() {  
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api-url/projects")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        request.addValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authentication-Key")
        request.addValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authentication-Secret")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            let projectList = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Projects.self, from: data)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.projectList = projectList
                print(self.projectList)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @ObservedObject var networkingManager = NetworkingManager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(networkingManager.projectList.data, id: \.id) { project in
                HStack {
                    Text(project.id)
                    Text(project.url)

                }

            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

This results in a list of id and url string values but my question is: How can I list multiple levels of the json files. Do I have to decode each level of the json I want to use or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was less complicated than I thought. I got a nil value back when I was calling `project_status?.label`
this was resolved when I called it like this:
`project_status?.label ?? self.defaultString`